# Determine if Kinect is plugged in using Microsoft SDK or ManagementObjectSearcher

Tags: c#, wpf, usb, kinect

I'm trying to determine if my Kinect is plugged into the PC using the ManagementObjectSearcher. I'm not sure what to query because it is NOT listed as a USB Device. Instead it is listed as a "Microsoft Kinect" hardware device.

[image]

Below is what I'm going fussing with:

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * from Win32_SOMETYPE"))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in searcher.Get())
    {
        foreach (PropertyData propertyData in managementObject.Properties)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some context about how this should be used?  For example, do you want to detect the presence of Kinect after the user has launched an app, or is this something you want to run in the system tray listening for a new Kinect connection?

Comment: I want to detect if the Kinect is plugged in. I need to initialize my app differently if this is plugged in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the latest Windows SDK, here is some example code to get available Kinect connections:

```
     switch (Runtime.Kinects.Count)
    {
        case 0:
            //Do something if none.
            break;
        default:
            //Do something if present.
            break;
    }
```

Good Luck!

Matt

Comment: Yes, but I need to determine this even before I call the Microsoft DLL.

Comment: Are you sure it matters when you initialize the Kinect DLL?  I would think that you could just use the Kinect DLL to call the above code in your app's initialize() method.  If you don't initialize the Kinect SDK to detect the presence of a Kinect, I don't know how you would do it.  Sorry I can't help.

Comment: eh just tried it. Yea I suppose this works for what I need to do...thanks

Comment: I always seem to start with the harder solution first.

Comment: Is there any reason this is in a switch as opposed to `if(Runtime.Kinects.Count == 0)`?